# How do I run a CONCAT on query stored in a database

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I know this is a bad example but I'm trying to simplify things so bear with me in the round-about way this code is written.  Say I have queries stored in a database such as

### queries table

```
id    query
1     concat('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE year = ', _year, 'order by name')
2     concat('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE year = ', _year, 'order by name')
```

---

and I want to run the following routine

```
DECLARE _year;
SET _year= "2013";
SET @SQL = (SELECT query FROM queries WHERE id = 1);    
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

this is what I currently have but it's not working.  I'm trying to select a query from the database, pass a few variables into it and then run the query.

Comment: MySQL does not not allow dynamic SQL in stored procedures.

Comment: Then can anyone point me in the right direction on a different way to do this that still involves storing queries and variables in the database and then building a statement from those.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to determine your query in advance, except for specific parameters, then you could consider using a UNION query with a discriminant. Then, use your queries table to select specific queries in the union and apply parameters to them. The queries themselves are defined in a view in the database.

SQL is intended in most DBMS to not be dynamic and the attempt to subvert this will almost certainly result in reduced performance and potential security problems.

```
CREATE VIEW UnionView
AS SELECT *, 1 as Type, Value1 AS Param FROM Table1 
UNION ALL SELECT *, 2 as Type, Value2 AS Param FROM Table1
UNION ALL SELECT *, 3 as Type, Value3 AS Param FROM Table1;

SELECT * FROM UnionView WHERE Type = 2 AND Param = 2;
```

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d67a9/1/0) for an example to  demonstrate the behaviour.